# ElasticSearch architecture with Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, docker, elasticsearch

I need to connect an ElasticSearch (ES) cluster to an existing website architecture. The current architecture is a Mysql database connected with a Drupal CMS.

The question is: what is the best approach to create a syncronized architecture between ES and the website database?

In a developement context I created a docker with 4 containers:

- ES
- Mysql (to simulate the website database)
- Logstash (as a pipeline between the Mysql container and ES container working with JDBC)
- Kibana (server to visualize ES cluster)

[image]

This works really well! But it raises some problems to integrate it:

- The Mysql container needs .sql files (a corresponding dump from the actual website Mysql database) to initialize so it is not syncronized with the actual database.
- Data is now duplicated between Mysql and ES (is it a problem?).

Is this implementation of ES a good approach? How to syncronize it with website architecture?

What I think might do the job is to connect Mysql container to website Mysql with a cronjob every day to keep syncronization and to request ES from the CMS (see below).

[image]

Comment: `Data is now duplicated between Mysql and ES (is it a problem?)` I will say **NO** because there are lot of usecase in which we use elasticsearch as secondary data store. You can minimize data duplication by just indexing data into elasticsearch which is required for search and showing in search result.

Comment: @SagarPatel Thank you for your quick reply! I already just indexed the needed data but if I remove one sample from the database it will still be in ES right? Could this be a problem since it could still appear in search response?

Comment: You can use soft delete. So you can add one field in database which indicate if recoreds is deleted or not and when you are processing recored using logstash then you can check that field value and based on thet you can set document operation like insert or delete. This will help you to delete recored from Elasticsearch as well